# php not connecting to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

so I installed WAMP and a mysql database (not using the one that comes with wamp). I can connect from MySql Workbench to the server but not from the php page. They are both on the same machine and the script looks like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT
{

    // constructor
    function __construct()
    {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct()
    {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect()
    {
        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:3306", "userMan", "passDoor") or die(mysql_error());

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysql_select_db("testdb") or die(mysql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */
    function close()
    {
        // closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }
}

?>
```

This row:

> $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:3306", "userMan", "passDoor") or
>   die(mysql_error());

Tells me:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in
>   C:\wamp\www\website\db_connect.php on line 32

It worked before but now "suddenly" it stopped working, any thoughts?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to use mysqli instead since mysql_* is deprecated and so I did this:

I find hte php.ini being used from phpinfo() and make sure these are uncommented:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

I also tried this with commenting php_mysql.dll,

I add this to my php script to see if it works:

```
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli'))
        {
            echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!!';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Phew we have it!';
        }
```

and my result is "We don't have mysqli!!!".

I am running wamp on windows 8.1, php is version 5.4.12 and I have also checked that the extension_dir in php.ini is correct.

What may I be doing wrong?

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions. They've been deprecated.

Comment: I made an update about problems with trying to use mysqli instead.

Comment: I solved this by uninstalling wamp and installing apache + php manually.

Answer (score 2):

Your mysql driver is not loaded. Uncomment `extension=php_mysql.dll` in `php.ini`. Also I suggest you to use [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). You are using deprecated one.

In order to find `php.ini` location, you can use `php --ini` in commandline

Comment: ok so I ent in to php.ini and did this: `extension=php_mysql.dll`
and `extension=php_mysqli.dll` and then I check if I have mysqli extension like this: `if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli'))` and it tells me that I don't have it. I also did a reboot after. I made sure the dll file exists in the extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/"

Comment: If it exists remove comment at the end. Of not,  add it